# \stackrel{-}{x} of different letters makes overline at different quote

Tags: math-mode, stacking-symbols

I'm writing my PhD Thesis. I have a stylistic problem with an equation. These are the code and the output (the red lines are mine).

```
Per ovviare a questi due inconvenienti si è ritenuto opportuno definire un coefficiente normalizzato di questo tipo:

\begin{equation} \label{eq:new-ri2}
\widetilde{RI} = \stackrel{-}{q}\stackrel{-}{v}^{\stackrel{-}{\gamma}} \frac{RI}{\hat{q}v^\gamma},
\end{equation}

dove $\stackrel{-}{q}$, $\stackrel{-}{v}$ e $\stackrel{-}{\gamma}$ sono i parametri medi di $\hat{q}$, $v$ e $\gamma$. Il loro prodotto è un coefficiente avente
```

[image: In this equation the]

I would like that the `\stackrel{-}{q}` and the `\stackrel{-}{v}` gives me a overline at the same height, but with the `v` letter the overline is more down (as shown by the red lines).

Comment: Is there a particular reason as why you are using `\stackrel{-}{q}` instead of simply `\bar{q}`?

Comment: No, and... `\bar{q}` solves my problem. I did not think to this solution. Please, write the answer, if you want.

Comment: Don't use blank lines above `equation` environments. A blank line below it *can* be used, if the text starts a new paragraph, which is not the case here. And don't set `\parindent` to zero, your readers will appreciate.

Comment: Yes @egreg, I know, but in this case the all the \newline are with \noindent. ;-)

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni If you use `\newline` or ``\\`` in normal text more than occasionally, it means you're not using LaTeX correctly. And using `\noindent` is the same.

Comment: @egreg, of course I do not user `\\` in every paragraph. And you have reason: I have do not insert blank line after `equation`. Thanks.

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni You should use ``\\`` in ***no*** paragraph.

Comment: Mmm... true, but... in the authors field, sometime is helpful for divide better the authors' name. Or in `caption` environment. No other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: for heaven's sake, don't use `\stackrel{-}{q}` in that way but simply `\bar{q}` :-)

The longer version: let's give a look at the definition of `\stackrel`:

```
\def\stackrel#1#2{\mathrel{\mathop{#2}\limits^{#1}}}
```

The second argument of `\stackrel{-}{q}` is made a math operator (`\mathop`). This has the consequence that the character is centered on the math axis. Compare e.g.

[image]

So in your case the trouble is not that the bar (actually: a minus sign) is higher, but the whole letter is higher.

Second problem: the whole thing is made a math relation (`\mathrel`): this affects the spacing and squeezes the `\stackrel{-}{q}` close to the `=`, as you may see in your result.

(If for some obscure reason your really did not want to use `\bar`, at least use the `\overset` macro from `amsmath`.)

Comment: By the way, `\overset` of `amsmath` takes care of both bad aspects in `\stackrel`. Not that I recommend `\overset{-}{p}` in this case, of course.

Comment: @egreg Yep, wrote it. I guess I edited my answer as you were writing your comment...